# FileHelpers cannot map converted field into destination array

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csv, filehelpers

I have the following record (reduced for brevity):

```
 [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    [IgnoreFirst]
    [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
    public class ImportRecord
    {
        [FieldQuoted]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string FirstName;

        [FieldQuoted]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public string LastName;

        [FieldQuoted]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        [FieldOptional]
        [FieldConverter(typeof(TestPropertyConverter))]
        public int[] TestProperty;    
    }
```

Converter code:

```
  public class TestPropertyConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object StringToField(string from)
        {
              var ret = from.Split('|').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
              return ret;
        }
    }
```

So an example record could be:
**John, Smith, 1|2|3|4**

It would expect the values 1,2,3,4 to expand and fill the TestProperty array. However, I'm getting the following exception:

**At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.**

I've tried to debug into the code and it seems to blow-up in the ExtractFieldValue() function inside FieldBase.cs where it tries to return out of the function.
The following line seems to be the culprit:

```
res.ToArray(ArrayType);
```

It seems to expect the 'res' variable to be the destination type array, but it contains 1 element of the array itself.

Can anyone suggest if I'm doing this wrong or a possible fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to handle the parsing in an `AfterReadRecord` event.  This is useful when the parsing of the array field is complex.  (A custom converter is less powerful and does not give you, e.g., `e.SkipThisRecord`).

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
//[IgnoreFirst]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class ImportRecord
{
    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string FirstName;

    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string LastName;

    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldOptional]
    public string TestProperty;

    [FieldIgnored] // <-- this field is ignored by the FileHelpers engine
    public int[] ParsedTestProperty; 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ImportRecord>();
        engine.AfterReadRecord += engine_AfterReadRecord;

        string fileAsString = @"John, Smith, 1|2|3|4" + Environment.NewLine;
        ImportRecord[] validRecords = engine.ReadString(fileAsString);
        Assert.AreEqual("John", validRecords[0].FirstName);
        Assert.AreEqual("Smith", validRecords[0].LastName);
        Assert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, validRecords[0].ParsedTestProperty);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, AfterReadEventArgs<ImportRecord> e)
    {
        e.Record.ParsedTestProperty = e.Record.TestProperty.Split('|').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write a converter.  You just need to change the field delimiter for the last field.  The following example works:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
//[IgnoreFirst]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class ImportRecord
{
    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string FirstName;

    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    public string LastName;

    [FieldQuoted]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldOptional]
    [FieldDelimiter("|")] // <-- here 
    public int[] TestProperty;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ImportRecord>();
        string fileAsString = @"John, Smith, 1|2|3|4" + Environment.NewLine;
        ImportRecord[] validRecords = engine.ReadString(fileAsString);
        Assert.AreEqual("John", validRecords[0].FirstName);
        Assert.AreEqual("Smith", validRecords[0].LastName);
        Assert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, validRecords[0].TestProperty);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your help with this. My example is a little more simple than my actual problem, and I need to be able to return from my converter. My actual application has multiple notes that need to be imported which use single and double pipe characters e.g. 2011-01-01T10:00|Note1||2011-02-01T11:00|Note 2|| etc...Do you think there is a solution for this?

Comment: If it's that complicated, it's might be easier to change `TestProperty` to a plain `String` and then do a `foreach` over the resulting`ImportRecords` in order to parse the `TestProperty` further.  But see my answer other for another approach.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for bumping up this old question, but I just had the same problem and I have found a much easier solution to this problem.

It seems that FileHelpers handles arrays in special way and expects values to be delimited with separator indicated by `DelimitedRecord` attribute. Therefore it tries to call custom converter on each delimited record and expects you to return element type.

In my case I had bit map (`010100101001010101001010001101`) field without any delimiter that I wanted to convert into `bool[]`. I went in the source code and found out that `typeof(T).IsArray` is used to determine this behavior.

So, long story short, it is enough to change array into list.

Instead of:

```
public int[] TestProperty;
```

Change into:

```
public List<int> TestProperty;
```

And also modify custom converter to return a list:

```
return from.Split('|').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```